# Control audio file sound

Tags: android

I am playing a beep sound for the last 5 seconds on a Timer.

I want to regulate the volume of the audio file with the volume keys of the mobile device.

I am currently using the android.media.SoundPool class to play the two audio files used for the Timer.

I am using the following method to play the sound:

```
public static void playSound(int index, float speed) {
        float streamVolume = mAudioManager
                .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        streamVolume = streamVolume
                / mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(index), 1, 1,
                1, 0, speed);
    }
```

Currently I am able to play both the audio files but want to control with the mobile device volume keys.

Kindly provide your inputs/sample code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Call [`setVolumeControlStream()`](http://goo.gl/iNn8d) on your activity, and the volume buttons will control your desired stream.